# How can I efficiently extract variables from JSON with xonsh?

Tags: jq, xonsh

Given a variable `AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE` that contains the output of the `aws sts assume-role` (a JSON string), I can write the following in `bash`.

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$( jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' <<<$AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE )
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$( jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' <<<$AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE )
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$( jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken' <<<$AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE )

aws sts get-caller-identity
```

However, in order to get the same functionality in `xonsh`, I need two `echo` commands.

```
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = $( echo -n @$( echo @(AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE) | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId') )
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = $( echo -n @$( echo @(AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE) | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' ) )
$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN     = $( echo -n @$( echo @(AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE) | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken' ) )

aws sts get-caller-identity
```

The inner one to provide `jq` with the input data. The outer one to be able to set the corresponding environment variable with a string value without a new line.

Okay, a little awkward but not too bad. However, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: As an aside, there are more efficient ways to do that in bash. For example, `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN < <(jq -r '.Credentials | ( .AccessKeyId, .SecretAccessKey, .SessionToken )' <<<"$AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE" && printf '\0')` lets you capture all three variables from only one invocation of `jq`.

Comment: More efficient but less readable, IMHO. Anyway, it's worthwhile for those scripts that have to parse big json files.Thank you, @CharlesDuffy.

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is a great tool -- for this particular case with `xonsh`, I'd lean on the `json` module instead, though.
Assuming that `AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE` is some stringified json blob:

```
import json

blob = json.loads(AWS_ASSUMED_ROLE)
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = blob["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"]
...
```

Comment: Thank you, @GilForsyth. I was imagining that was the best approach. My aim was to promote `xonsh` in my IaC team. They are bash programmers and I I wanted that transition from bash to python were as smooth as possible. However, I feel there is some room of improvement when a python variable has to injected into the standard input of another subprocess.